# Concatenate Pandas pipe and apply to rows

Tags: python, pandas, pipe, assign

I have the following code:

```
df = (
            df
            .pipe(function_1)
            .pipe(function_2)
        )

# Apply the policy
df["prediction"] = df.apply(
            lambda row: function_3(row, input_dict), axis=1,
        )

# Keep only rows of interest
df = df.query("prediction>0")
```

I'd like to concatenate, within a single call:

- 2x pipe
- apply to define a new variable
- query command

For simplicity, function_1 and function_2 are generic functions that only return the DataFrame and function_3 accepts as input a row from a DataFrame and a pre-defined dictionary.

I tried with:

```
df1 = (
    df
    .pipe(function_1)
    .pipe(function_2)
    .assign(
        prediction = lambda row: function_3(row, input_dict), axis=1
        )
    .query("prediction>0")
)
```

But it raises, due to the "assign" method:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using apply directly to the element and setting axis=1:

```
df1 = (
    df
    .pipe(function_1)
    .pipe(function_2)
    .assign(
        prediction = lambda row: row.apply(function_3, input_dict=input_dict, axis=1)
        )
    .query("prediction>0")
)
```